# Mouse sending spurious x11 event (scroll right button)

Tags: x11, mouse, xinput

I have an annoying problem where my mouse seems to somewhat randomly emit a 'Scroll right' event (button press 7).

I am running Debian Buster on my main desktop at the moment.  I have not made any explicit changes to my mouse's configuration (remapping, etc).

The only somewhat relevant change I have made recently was installing xpra, so that I can remote into my desktop.  I have done some basic troubleshooting which I believe basically rules this out.

Basic troubleshooting steps:

1. Did a reboot
2. Purged xpra and did a reboot
3. Disconnected mouse dongle and put in different port.
4. Replaced batteries in mouse
5. Moved keyboard to different USB port.
6. Ran xinput to figure out the mouse is spitting out button press 7:

```
   button release 7
   button release 7
   button release 7
   button release 7
   button press   7
   button press   7
   button release 7
   button press   7
```

7. Noticed, in xinput, that the problem is much worse in firefox-esr (but something perhaps related appears to happen, for example, in the volume mixer at the top of the default Debian window manager.)  That is to say, xinput sees lots of spurious events when a firefox window is active.
8. It also seems to happen in Citrix, so maybe there is a commonality like GTK or something (but I don't know the internals of either firefox or Citrix).
9. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
10. Tried the mouse on a different machine.

So far, nothing has worked.  Little help?  Thank you!

Comment: Could you check if the same behavior occurs on a different machine?

Comment: I don't have another machine with a similar environment already set up.  I can try my mouse on a Windows PC, etc.  (All but one of my Debian machines are dedicated to being hypervisors, with no X11)

Comment: A windows machine would also be fine as it would exclude a hardware issue

Comment: I tried the mouse on a Windows PC and it appears to be working correctly.